# Is it better to use bind() or not in terms of memory savings?

Tags: jquery

Which one of these is considered better code and why and what is better on memory?

Say your jquery code looks like example one without bind();

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#someDiv').mouseenter(function(){
         $('#someDiv').fadeTo('fast',1);
      });
      $('#someDiv').mouseleave(function(){
         $('#someDiv').fadeTo('fast', .5);
      });    
   });
```

Or with bind() method.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#someDiv').bind({
       mouseenter: function(){
         $('#someDiv').fadeTo("fast",1);
       },
       mouseleave:  function(){
         $('#someDiv').fadeTo("fast",0.5);
       )
     })
  });
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to change `$('#someDiv').fadeTo` to `$(this).fadeTo`

Comment: Yeah your right.  I was just throwing up a quick example, but yeah the $(this) does make better sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no difference. All the different ways of binding event handlers in jQuery eventually call the same internal function to actually perform the binding. Here's a simplified view of how it works:

```
bind: function(bindings) {
    for (event in bindings) {
        return this.on(event, bindings[event]);
    },
mouseenter: function(handler) {
    return this.on("mouseenter", handler);
},
mouseleave: function(handler) {
    return this.on("mouseleave", handler);
}
```

BTW, `.bind()` is outdated, although it's not yet deprecated. `.on()` is preferred unless you need to be compatible with jQuery versions before 1.7.

Comment: Would the code look the same with .on()?  Another words would I just have to replace bind() with on()?

Comment: yes, you can simply replace `bind` with `on`. The only case where this isn't compatible is if you use the optional `preventBubble` argument.